# Looking for a good C++ library for parsing AMF3

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, amf

What's a good C++ library for parsing AMF3?

Answer (score 2):

Based on some simple research, [libamfx](http://code.google.com/p/libamfx/) doesn't support AMF3 and [amf3cplusplus](http://code.google.com/p/amf3cplusplus/) isn't a complete implementation of the specs, although it may work for your needs. There don't appear to be any pure-C libraries, so the next place to look would be C language extensions.

There is a fully functional AMF implementation in C for PHP ([AMFEXT](http://pecl.php.net/package/amfext)), a C implementation for Python ([PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/index.html)), one for Objective-C ([Cocoa-AMF](https://github.com/nesium/cocoa-amf)), and one for Ruby ([RocketAMF](https://github.com/rubyamf/rocketamf)). However, none of these are going to be drop-in solutions.

Your best bet would be to try out amf3cplusplus and see if it does what you want. If it doesn't, RocketAMF is probably going to be the easiest to use as a starting point, in terms of readability and replacing the language-specific code with C++ data structures.

Comment: I tried to use amf3cplusplus but it can't parse amf-files I have. I guess there are elements this parser doesn't support. I'll try RocketAMF

Answer (score 0):

I understood that libamfx actualy good.
Did you try it  ?

Comment: libamfx doesn't support AMF3, so it's not going to work for his needs.

Comment: Hi Mihai, I have a problem using libamfx, see http://code.google.com/p/libamfx/issues/detail?id=3

Comment: libamfx is not good for amf3. It doesn't support