# C++ <-> AS3 Object serialization

Tags: c++, actionscript-3

Is it technically possible to serialize an object in C++ to send it via a socket and de-serialize in AS3 (bi-directionally)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. This only possible when you use same language with same serilazation/deserialization on both sides. You have to develop and use some custom protocol to send object states via socket. Read more about [Google Protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding).

> Thanks to chac - [As3 Google Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-actionscript3/)

Comment: I found something [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns)

Comment: Changed url to encoding. This will help to understand idea of serialization datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the previous answer, it should be possible with some work. There are quite a lot of Flash remoting implementations using [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) (from Java, PHP, Python). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349052/looking-for-a-good-c-library-for-parsing-amf3).

Answer (score 0):

you'll need an AMF lib, and the only ones I'm aware of are very linked to the PHP stack. Look around, you might find a pure C/C++ one though. If you're desperate one possibility might be to look at Haxe, which has an AMF implementation, and compile it to C++