# Script to binary conversion & Object serialization

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, flash, serialization, scripting

All the code I write (C++ or AS3) is heavily scripted (JSON or XML). My problem is that parsing can be very slow at times, especially with less powerful devices like mobiles.

Here is an example of a Flash script of mine:

```
        <players class="fanlib.gfx.TSprite" vars="x=0|y=-50|visible=Bool:true">
            <player0 class="fanlib.gfx.TSprite" vars="x=131|y=138">
                <name class="fanlib.text.TTextField" format="Myriad Pro,18,0xffffff,true,,,,,center,,,,0" alignX="center" alignY="bottom" filters="DropShadow,2" vars="background=Bool:false|backgroundColor=0|embedFonts=Bool:true|multiline=Bool:false|mouseEnabled=Bool:false|autoSize=center|text=fae skata|y=-40"/>
                <avatar class="fanlib.gfx.FBitmap" alignX="center" alignY="center" image="userDefault.png"/>
                <chip class="fanlib.gfx.FBitmap" alignX="center" alignY="center" image="chip1.png" vars="x=87|y=68"/>
                <info class="fanlib.text.TTextField" format="Myriad Pro,18,0xffffff,true,,,,,center,,,,0" alignX="center" alignY="top" filters="DropShadow,2" css=".win {color: #40ff40}" vars="y=40|background=Bool:false|backgroundColor=0|embedFonts=Bool:true|multiline=Bool:false|mouseEnabled=Bool:false|autoSize=center"/>
            </player0>

            <player1 class="Copy:player0" vars="x=430|y=70">
                <chip class="Child:chip" image="chip2.png" vars="x=-82|y=102"/>
            </player1>
            <player2 class="Copy:player0" vars="x=778|y=70">
                <chip class="Child:chip" image="chip3.png" vars="x=88|y=103"/>
            </player2>
            <player3 class="Copy:player0" vars="x=1088|y=137">
                <chip class="Child:chip" image="chip4.png" vars="x=-111|y=65"/>
            </player3>
            <player4 class="Copy:player0" vars="x=1088|y=533">
                <chip class="Child:chip" image="chip5.png" vars="x=-88|y=-23"/>
            </player4>
            <player5 class="Copy:player0" vars="x=585|y=585">
                <chip class="Child:chip" image="chip6.png" vars="x=82|y=-54"/>
            </player5>
            <player6 class="Copy:player0" vars="x=117|y=533">
                <chip class="Child:chip" image="chip7.png" vars="x=85|y=-26"/>
            </player6>
        </players>
```

The script above creates "native" (as in "non-dynamic") Flash objects. TSprite is a Sprite descendant, FBitmap inherits from Bitmap etc. At 71KBs, it takes tens of seconds to be parsed on my Sony XPeria.

Instead of optimizing the parser (which wouldn't probably gain too much anyway) I am contemplating converting my scripts to binaries, so that scripts will be used for debugging and the finalized binaries for release-built code.

One question is, how does one handle pointers from one object to another when serializing them? How are pointers translated from memory to disk file-friendly format,then back to memory?

Another question is, what about "nested" objects? In Flash for example, an object can be a graphics container of other objects. Could such a state be serialized? Or must objects be saved separately and, when loaded from disk, added to their parents through the nesting functions (i.e. addChild etc...)?

If possible, I would prefer generic guidelines that could apply to languages as different as C++ or AS3.

Comment: Does "parsing takes tens of seconds" mean literally just parsing? Or including object creation as it goes? We parse a similar amount (possibly slightly larger) on mobile devices and parse time is an order of magnitude faster. This makes me suspicious of what your parser is doing.

Comment: You are right, I mean the time taken for the whole lot. Plus it's faster than I originally calculated, yet my question still remains. After all, serialization is also supposed to speed up object creation since they are pre-created...or something.

Comment: I disagree with your last statement. Serialization is nothing to do with speed. Normally it is slower than creating the objects natively as it incurs parsing overhead and (typically) reflection costs. The only exception to this would be creating objects which are computationally intense after the computation had been done - but that's obvious. How many objects is your 10s script creating? Do you know which ones are slower than others? I would start here. Either looking at ways to fix it, or maybe look at lazy init of some of those objects if suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I've understood your idea is to save some time by replacing creation of the objects from some fixture script (xml/json) to deserializing (from binary) previously serialized objects. If that's the case I beleive that you've taken wrong approach to solve this issue.

Since you've asked for general guidelines I'll try to explain my reasoning, not delving too deeply into language-specific details. Note that I'll talk about the common case and there may be exceptions from it. There is no silver bullet and you should analyze your scenario to pick the best solution for it.

From one point of view creating set of objects based on fixture/script is not that different from deserializing objects from binary. In the end they both are about turning some "condensed" state into objects that you can use. Yes, it is true that binaries are usually smaller in size but formats like JSON have not that many overhead in *commomon case* (XML is *usually* more redundant though). *In general* you won't save much time/memory on **deserializing** this state from binary instead of **parsing** it from script. Here is a real world example from somthing I worked with: Mental Ray is a de-facto standard for rendering 3d scenes\special effects in a movie industry. It uses [textual file format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mi/) to represent scenes that is somewhat similar to JSON in many aspects. Mental Ray is heavy on computations, performance is one of the key issues here, yet it lives perfectly fine without binary scene file format. So, analyzing this aspect you can say that there is no substantial difference between these 2 approaches.

From another point of view, there is a difference that may come into play. While deserializing object implies only **creating object** and **loading state into it's fields**, creating object from script *may* also include some **extra initialization on top of that**. So, in some cases there may be benefit from using deserialization approach.

However, in the end I would argue that it is not a good idea to simply replase your scripted objects to serialized objects because scripting and serialization are **conceptually different things and have different purposes** (though they do have something in common). Using serialization approach you'll **loose flexibility in modifying your fixtured state** (it is usually much harder for humans to edit binaries instead of JSON/XML) **as well as ability to do initialization work**.

So, think about what you actually need in your scenario and stick with it. That's the best way.

Now, if it happen to be that you actually need your objects to be *scripted* but this approach is not fast enough I would investigate speeding it up in one of 2 ways:

1. Analyze whether it is possible to restructure your data the way it will take less time to load. This is not always possible, however, it might be worth trying it.
2. Analyze what else your scripting engine does to init object except of simply creating them and load state into their fields and try to optimize it. This approach is actually has the most potential since this is the only part that has substantional difference in terms of performance (between scripting and deserialization approach) and does not lead to misuse of concepts. Try to see whether you are able to reduce this amount of work, needed to init object. It may be a good idea to tailor something more specific for your needs if you are currently using some generic scripting engine\framework at the moment.

Now, answering your original questions...

> how does one handle pointers from one object to another when serializing them?

References are headache most of serialization implementations does not mess with.

One of the approaches is to use something to identify object during serialization (pointer, for example), serialize object preserving this this identity, and store references from another objects to this object not as primitive type, but as a reference type (basically saving identity). When deserializing - keep track of all deserialized objects and reuse them when deseializing reference typed field.

> How are pointers translated from memory to disk file-friendly format,then back to memory?

It is a rarity when serialization deals with raw memory. This approach is only good for primitive types and does not work with poiners/references well. Languages that support reflection\introspection usually use it to inspect values of the fields to serialize objects. If we talk about pure C++, where reflection is poor - there is no other reliable way except to make object itself define means to serialize itself to bytestream and use these methods.

> Another question is, what about "nested" objects? In Flash for example, an object can be a graphics container of other objects. Could such a state be serialized? Or must objects be saved separately and, when loaded from disk, added to their parents through the nesting functions (i.e. addChild etc...)?

If we talk about deserialization - these should probably be treated like references (see answer above). Using methods like `addChild` is not a good idea since it can contain some logic that will mess things.

Hope this answers your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should realty take a look at Adobe [Remote Object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_4.html).

Typically using serialization could cost you problems, such as:

- I have a serialized object from application version 2.3 and now at the new version 2.4 it been modified: property removed / property added. This makes my serialized object unparsable.
- While developing a serialization protocol that will support cross platform, you may actually wish to kill yourself while debugging. I remember myself doing this and I spent hours to find out that my flash using Big Indian and C# using Small Indian.

Adobe solved those problems for you, they created a nice binary protocol called [AMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) - **Action Message Format**. It have many implementations on various platforms that can communicate with your actions script.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349052/looking-for-a-good-c-library-for-parsing-amf3) you may find some C++ implementations.